# Rendering different images based on OS (iOS/Android)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, sfmc-business-unit

I am trying to implement the functionality of rendering different image based on the device's OS it is getting rendered on for eg: iOS, Android. I have written the below SSJS code in my Freeform block within Marketing Cloud and I am trying to print the Output of variable 'OS' in my code, but the output is always Unknown irrespective of the email being rendered in Android/iOS.

Here is the Code :

```
    <script runat="server">
  Platform.Load('Core','1.1.1');
  var OS;
  
  function getMobileOperatingSystem() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

      // Windows Phone must come first because its UA also contains "Android"
    if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Windows Phone";
    }

    if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Android";
    }

    // iOS detection
    if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        return "iOS";
    }

    return "unknown";
}
var OS = getMobileOperatingSystem();
  
   Variable.SetValue('@OSType',OS);
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using browser/client objects inside a server code. `navigator` and `window` are unavailable on server side.

To get UserAgent in SSJS retrieve it directly from the header with [GetRequestHeader()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformHTTPPropertyGetRequestHeader.htm):

```
var userAgent = Platform.Request.GetRequestHeader('User-Agent');
```

Comment: I tried and its the same output "unknown" for all scenarios. I think what I am trying to achieve is not possible through SSJS.